# Need Help dropping voltage on a signal wire

Tags: power, resistors, diodes

I am working with a Hall eletric throttle switch 0-5v operation. It is powered by 5v dc. The signal wire reads .86v when in the neutral position and 4.8v fully pressed. I need the starting point to be .5v or lower. Now the voltage of the signal wire needs to run between .5-4.5v as the switch is pressed. There is no load on the wire as it simply sends the voltage to the ecm to increase or decrease the throttle. What do I need to drop the voltage roughly .5 across the scale?

Comment: An opamp with slight gain and some offset?

Comment: A simple potential divider should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You have a voltage from 860 mV to 5 V and want to map that to 500 mV to 4.5 V.

Let's start by looking at the scale factor.  (4.5 V - 500 mV)/(5.0 V - 860 mV) = .97.  That's almost 1, so almost a pure level shifting problem.

Let's look at the level shift.  At the high end you want to drop it 500 mV and at the low en 360 mV.  That's not too far off from a silicon diode drop.  You might be able to get away with putting a diode in series with the signal.  Anode to Hall device, cathode to the ECM with a pulldown resistor.

It's hard to know what the pulldown resistor value should be since you haven't said anything about the current capabilities of the Hall device nor the impedance of the ECM input.  Start with 10 kΩ and adjust from there.

Comment: maybe a schottky diode would be a better match here.

Comment: @Jasen Agreed, a Schottky with a Vfd of 0.3V in series with the signal would do the job absolutely fine.

Comment: @Jasen: Maybe.  At the likely low currents with a reasonable pulldown, a silicon diode might only drop 500-600 mV, and a Schottky 200-300 mV.  The best answer is to try both and see what works best.